# Systemd RequiredBy directive is ignored

Tags: debian, systemd, systemd-boot

Here's my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Blabla service
Requires=network-online.target nfs-common.service
After=network-online.target nfs-common.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/script
RemainAfterExit=no

[Install]
RequiredBy=php5-fpm.service apache2.service nginx.service
```

When enabling it looks promising:

```
# systemctl enable blabla.service 
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/php5-fpm.service.requires/blabla.service to /etc/systemd/system/blabla.service.
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/apache2.service.requires/blabla.service to /etc/systemd/system/blabla.service.
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.requires/blabla.service to /etc/systemd/system/blabla.service.
```

Then after the restart `systemd-analyze` gives me the following:

```
# systemd-analyze blame
         18.434s blabla.service
          5.942s cloud-init.service
          2.766s networking.service
          1.671s apache2.service
          1.398s cloud-init-local.service
          1.276s newrelic-sysmond.service
           856ms php5-fpm.service
           586ms nginx.service
           .....
```

According to docs `Type=oneshot`:

> Behavior of oneshot is similar to simple; however, it is expected that the process has to exit before systemd starts follow-up units.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? Start `blabla.service` before `php5-fpm.service apache2.service nginx.service`?

Comment: Yes, only when `blabla.service` finishes `php5-fpm.service`,  `apache2.service` , `nginx.service` should carry on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RequiredBy=` does not imply that one service should start after another.

In `man systemd.unit`, the docs for `RequiredBy=` say:

> The primary result is that the current unit will be started when the listed unit is started.

In other words, they could end up started in parallel.  I think you want a `Before=` directive in your install section. The docs in `man systemd.unit` have this to say about `Before=`:

> If a unit foo.service contains a setting Before=bar.service and both
>              units are being started, bar.service's start-up is delayed until foo.service is started up. Note that this setting is independent of and orthogonal to the
>              requirement dependencies as configured by Requires=.

Comment: `Before` is not allowed in the `[Install]` section.